# Excavator badge not being awarded

Tags: support, badges

I edited an [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3963833/820021) that was inactive for more than 6 months, but wasn't awarded the Excavator badge. Why?

Although it is not specified in the badge criteria, but does the post being negatively scored have anything to do with this?

Comment: Wait a day and see.  Some badges are awarded only once a day  The three Excavator badges awarded today all show the time was "11 hours ago".  Probably your badge will be awarded 13 hours from now.

Comment: This badge is awarded one time only, not one time a day. Besides I was just awarded a different badge `Yearling`. Why would there be any different behavior between them?

Comment: Tomorrow we will find out if I am right.

Comment: Without knowing how the code is written, it is possible that some badges can be awarded immediately because the action is something that is checked for in regularly executed code, and some are awarded when a cron- or database- job is run -- which can be once a day, once an hour, once a week... whenever.  Since badges do not convey privileges I doubt that their award is a high priority.  @GEdgar is almost certainly right :)

Comment: @NadAlaba I believe that you have misunderstood GEdgar.  He is not saying that you can earn the badge once every day. He is suggesting that the script which awards the badge may only run once a day, hence everyone who earns the badge on a given day will have it awarded at the end of that day.

Comment: Or what @postmortes said.  Seems that's what I get for leaving a tab open for half an hour before getting to it. :D

Comment: Yes you were right, I've just been awarded the badge. Thank you all!

Comment: That was only about 12 hours after the previous Excavator badges.  From this timing, we can guess that Excavator badges are awarded twice a day.